# Dynamic updating referenced cell from another workbook after adding/deleting rows using IMPORTRANGE - use ARRAY or VLOOKUP?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, importrange, vlookup, google-sheets-arrayformula

I add/deleted/move rows frequently in my workbooks. When I add/remove rows from Spreadsheet#1 (**"S1"**), I need the referenced cell in Spreadsheet#2 (**"S2"**) to dynamically update so it still references the correct value, even though the cell itself has changed. Cell values may change as they update based on a `MIN` formula.

I've used the `IMPORTRANGE` function to populate the info from **"S1"** into **"S2"**. 
The range from **"S1"** is actually just a specific cell in **"S1"**.

`IMPORTRANGE` works fine when the values change. However, the issue arises when I add/delete a row. It references the same cell from **"S1"** (cell `M51`), which is now blank, instead of automatically updating its reference to the correct cell (after adding a row, `M51` becomes `M52`).

Example:

- Original Value in "S1" for `L51`: "next orange"
- What I want to happen: After adding row in **"S1"**, **"S2"** `A3` updates reference to cell `L52`. Now, `A3` displays: "next orange"
- Originally, `A3` in **"S2"** referenced cell `M51` from **"S1"**. `M51` uses `MIN` formula to pull minimum dates from `L:L` in **"S1"**
- After adding row in **"S1"**, **"S2"** cell `A3` should reference `M52` from **"S1"**
- However, **"S2"** cell `A3` references `M51` (which now contains the wrong value)

---

What I've tried/why it won't work:

1. duplicate/copy sheet from **S1** to **S2**: redundancy. I want **S2** to dynamically update when I update **S1**. don't want to update both **S1** and **S2** each time
2. didn't work: tried using absolute reference `$M$51` but doesn't reference correct cell after adding/removing rows
3. didn't work: modifying `IMPORTRANGE` with [`address`](https://www.coalmarch.com/insights/fill-import-range) but doesn't reference correct cell after adding/removing rows
4. didn't work: tried using this Google Sheets [script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32959875/synchronize-independent-spreadsheet-rows-filled-by-importrange) but got an error
5. `MATCH` function: since my range is simply an individual cell (`M51`), I cannot call out the range. cell `M51`uses a `MIN` function and won't be static; it can change as I add/remove rows
6. `array`: not sure how to do this with `IMPORTRANGE`
7. `VLOOKUP`: created a tab in **"S2"** that populated the sheet from **"S1"** using `VLOOKUP`. however, when I reference my `VLOOKUP` tab, it is still tied to the original referenced cells and does not update the reference (in **"S2"** cell `D2`: `='VLOOKUP of S1:"Added rows: Test w VLOOKUP"'!M51` but I want it to update the formula to `=VLOOKUP of S1:"Added rows: Test w VLOOKUP"'!M50` after adding 3 rows)

---

Test docs:

Spreadsheet1: [S1](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/13evadbMLzvQVSGbYssn_0deFdcmb5l3sqpeFgcNTjOY/edit#gid=1398857305) please make a copy of "Sheet7" tab

Spreadsheet2: [S2](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1R1T6YSfEQdn4qVcULJ1hNehEfDBZJNaTv1jJpaALJQk/edit#gid=234081248) please make a copy of "TO EDIT" tab

---

Would appreciate some assistance figuring this out. I need `M50:M59` (from **"S1"**) to populate into `A2:A11` ( in **"S2"**). My actual source spreadsheet (not linked) has tons of data (range `A1:AF70`) and I add/delete/move rows often.

If I add a row to **"S1"**, how can I ensure `M51` will update in **"S2"** to `M52`? Is there a way to combine `ARRAY` or `VLOOKUP` with `IMPORTRANGE` when my column headers are different?

Answer (score 0):

this can be achieved by adding an extra column far away, where it can be hidden and then populating this column by joining desired set of cells by unique separator until split will occur on the second spreadsheet. note that:

- adding or deleting rows will not affect dynamicity of `IMPORTRANGE`
- adding deleting columns will break all imported data
- there is no need for an extra column if there is a unique separator per every `IMPORTRANGE` of data and the search is applied always to such unique separator

in this particular case, there was used column **AG** from which `IMPORTRANGE` was fed.

in **Spreadsheet1** in **Sheet1!AG** (no matter of row number) there are formulas which `JOIN` content of **L50** and **M50** as well as the content of **L51** and **M51**, etc... (no matter if it's done directly or indirectly as far as the output is `TEXT`):

```
=JOIN("¤"; L50; MIN(FILTER(L:L; ISNUMBER(SEARCH("*banana*"; P:P))     
                               +ISNUMBER(SEARCH("*banana*"; Q:Q))
                               +ISNUMBER(SEARCH("*banana*"; R:R)))))
```

> **outputing:** **`next banana¤30-Aug-2004`**

---

```
=JOIN("¤"; L51; MIN(FILTER(L:L; ISNUMBER(SEARCH("*orange*"; P:P))     
                               +ISNUMBER(SEARCH("*orange*"; Q:Q))
                               +ISNUMBER(SEARCH("*orange*"; R:R)))))
```

> **outputing:** **`next orange¤2-Oct-2003`**

---

```
=JOIN("♥"; L52; AVERAGE(FILTER(L:L; ISNUMBER(SEARCH("orange"; P:P))
                                   +ISNUMBER(SEARCH("orange"; Q:Q))
                                   +ISNUMBER(SEARCH("orange"; R:R)))))
```

> **outputing:** **`X♥25-Sep-2013`**

---

```
=JOIN("♀"; L53; MIN(FILTER(L5:L48; ISNUMBER(SEARCH("*banana*"; Q5:Q48))
                                  *ISNUMBER(SEARCH("open";     R5:R48)))))
```

> **outputing:** **`next banana♀20-Aug-2000`**

---

```
=JOIN("♂"; L54; AVERAGEIFS(M5:M48; R5:R48; "open", 
                                   Q5:Q48; "*banana*"))
```

> **outputing:** **`avg days open (banana)♂74.41`**

---

```
=JOIN("♪"; L55; Q50/Q51)
```

> **outputing:** **`util♪0.370544987`**

---

```
=JOIN("♫"; L56; MINIFS(M5:M48; R5:R48; "open", 
                               Q5:Q48; "*banana*"))
```

> **outputing:** **`newest (mo)♫3.48`**

---

```
=JOIN("¤"; L57; M56*30.5)
```

> **outputing:** **`newest(days)¤106.2580645`**

---

```
=JOIN("♤"; L58; M58)
```

> **outputing:** **`avg LMT♤25051.35484`**

at this point, it doesn't matter if the format of joined cells is outputting elsehow (eg. 2nd part of the output should be formatted as **`$`**, **`%`**, **`mm/dd/yyyy`**) because in **Spreadsheet2** after splitting you can format it back as you wish

in **Spreadsheet2** you are free to paste following formula at any column and any row as well as you are free to:

- add or delete any rows in **Spreadsheet1**
- and add or delete any rows or columns in **Spreadsheet2**

---

```
 =SPLIT(
        ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(
                        QUERY(


        IMPORTRANGE("13evadbMLzvQVSGbYssn_0deFdcmb5l3sqpeFgcNTjOY"; "'Sheet1'!AG1:AG1000");

        "select Col1 where Col1 ='"&
        FILTER(

        IMPORTRANGE("13evadbMLzvQVSGbYssn_0deFdcmb5l3sqpeFgcNTjOY"; "'Sheet1'!AG1:AG1000");

                   ISNUMBER(
                            SEARCH("banana";

        IMPORTRANGE("13evadbMLzvQVSGbYssn_0deFdcmb5l3sqpeFgcNTjOY"; "'Sheet1'!AG1:AG1000"))

                   ))
                                    &"'"); 
                        1; 1); 
       "¤"; 1; 0)
```

this basically `SEARCH`es for text value `"banana"` in Spreadsheet1 under Sheet1 from range AG1:AG1000 and feed it to the `FILTER` which feeds criterion of `QUERY` which is `ARRAY_CONSTRAIN`ed to return one entry and that entry is `SPLIT` after unique separator `"¤"` (used earlier in `JOIN`) into two columns at the same row. and that's it.

if the content of cell **L50** is static like `banana` **and also unique per column** you can `SEARCH` for `"banana"` otherwise you need to use **unique separator per column** and `SEARCH` for such separator instead of `"banana"`

for a successful linkup, you need to be sure that separator in `SPLIT` matches separator in `JOIN` (`"¤"`). you can use any symbol you wish as the separator (**http://www.i2symbol.com/symbols**)

**example:** for formula **`=JOIN("♤"; L58; M58)`** you can use:

```
 =SPLIT(
        ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(
                        QUERY(


        IMPORTRANGE("13evadbMLzvQVSGbYssn_0deFdcmb5l3sqpeFgcNTjOY"; "'Sheet1'!AG1:AG1000");

        "select Col1 where Col1 ='"&
        FILTER(

        IMPORTRANGE("13evadbMLzvQVSGbYssn_0deFdcmb5l3sqpeFgcNTjOY"; "'Sheet1'!AG1:AG1000");

                   ISNUMBER(
                            SEARCH("lmt";

        IMPORTRANGE("13evadbMLzvQVSGbYssn_0deFdcmb5l3sqpeFgcNTjOY"; "'Sheet1'!AG1:AG1000"))

                   ))
                                    &"'"); 
                        1; 1); 
       "♤"; 1; 0)
```

**or**

```
 =SPLIT(
        ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(
                        QUERY(


        IMPORTRANGE("13evadbMLzvQVSGbYssn_0deFdcmb5l3sqpeFgcNTjOY"; "'Sheet1'!AG1:AG1000");

        "select Col1 where Col1 ='"&
        FILTER(

        IMPORTRANGE("13evadbMLzvQVSGbYssn_0deFdcmb5l3sqpeFgcNTjOY"; "'Sheet1'!AG1:AG1000");

                   ISNUMBER(
                            SEARCH("♤";

        IMPORTRANGE("13evadbMLzvQVSGbYssn_0deFdcmb5l3sqpeFgcNTjOY"; "'Sheet1'!AG1:AG1000"))

                   ))
                                    &"'"); 
                        1; 1); 
       "♤"; 1; 0)
```

**or**

```
 =SPLIT(
        ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(
                        QUERY(


        IMPORTRANGE("13evadbMLzvQVSGbYssn_0deFdcmb5l3sqpeFgcNTjOY"; "'Sheet1'!AG1:AG1000");

        "select Col1 where Col1 ='"&
        FILTER(

        IMPORTRANGE("13evadbMLzvQVSGbYssn_0deFdcmb5l3sqpeFgcNTjOY"; "'Sheet1'!AG1:AG1000");

                   ISNUMBER(
                            SEARCH("avg LMT";

        IMPORTRANGE("13evadbMLzvQVSGbYssn_0deFdcmb5l3sqpeFgcNTjOY"; "'Sheet1'!AG1:AG1000"))

                   ))
                                    &"'"); 
                        1; 1); 
       "♤"; 1; 0)
```